# The patch size in train is different the one in test, so I don't knwo how to set tf.palceholder

Tags: tensorflow

My English is poor, and I will try my best to clarify my question.
I designed a convolutional network. In training procedure, I set a `tf.plcaeholder` as image input:

```
input=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[batchszie,patch_height,patch_width])
```

All of training patches are 128X128.
In training codes, I have to use `tf.reshape` to change the input to adapt my task, such as:

```
shape = input.get_shape().as_list()
input = tf.reshape(input, [ 2 * shape[0], 2 * shape[1]])
```

When the network is trained, I test it. But the sizes of test images are various. In test codes, I also design a `tf.placeholder` as input:

```
input=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1,None,None])
```

But `tf.reshape` occurs an error. Becuase `shape[0]` and `shape[1]` are `None`. `tf.reshape` cannot double a `Nonetype`.

How can I modify my code?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily the **batch** dimension can be left as `None` for your placeholders.

Sounds like you need this:

```py
  input=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,128,128])
```

Comment: Thank you. The test images are different sizes rather than 128*128. So I define the input as `input=tf.placeholder(tf.float,[1,None,None])` . `1` indiacte 1 test image.  `None` indicate unknown test image height and width. But the code has `input = tf.reshape(a,2*shape[1],2*shape[2])`. In training, yes, I can define `input=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,128,128])`, and `tf.reahspe` has certain shape[1]=128 and shape[2]=128. But in test, shape[1] and shape[2] are `none`, and tf.reshape doesn't support `Nonetype`.

Comment: ah - sounds like I misunderstood your issue - apologies

Comment: I want to test images with different sizes. And I will change the size of these test images in my task. But now the height and width of tf.placeholder are `None`, not a fixed number, and tf.reshape support to change fixed number 128X128 bu doesn't support to change `None`.

Comment: It's not your fault. I am blame for my limited expressive ability. Thanks again.